In ASP.NET MVC cshtml view with Data Tables Net Bootstrap 5 horizontal scroll headers not aligning with columns
I am using the Bootstrap 5 version of DataTables.Net. The table is set to responsive.
What is happening: when the page loads, the column headers are to the left and aren't aligning with the corresponding headers. However say in Chrome I right click and inspect which changes the screen size the alignment of the headers then happens. Any ideas?
JS:
 $(document).ready(function () {
       var table = $('#wdihtrTable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            rowReorder: true,


            scrollX: true,
            columnDefs: [
                { orderable: true, className: 'reorder', targets: 0 },
                { orderable: false, targets: '_all' }
            ]
        });
    });

View :
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="wdihtrTable" class="table table-borderless display nowrap">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">Dealer Number</th>
                <th class="text-center">Red Bar</th>
                <th class="text-center">Green Bar</th>
                <th class="text-center">Blue Bar</th>
                <th class="text-center">Yellow Bar</th>
                <th class="text-center">Grey Bar</th>
                <th class="text-center">Dark Grey Bar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
             @foreach (var dealer in Model.DealerOpportunities)
             {
                 @await Html.PartialAsync("Components/WDIHTR/_DealerOpportunities", dealer)
             }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

Initial page load:

After screen size change:

